# raspberry pi rfid basics

Tags: raspberry-pi, nfc, rfid

i need help with the basics, im new to raspberry pi's and rfid, i want to create a program or script that can read all the datablocks of a card and dump it to a text file. as well as a program/script that will allow me to write datablocks to the card

Comment: can you please show us your effort behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import nxppy
import time

mifare = nxppy.Mifare()
try:
        while True:
                try:
                        uid= mifare.select()
                        print(uid)
                except nxppy.SelectError:

                        pass
                time.sleep(0.2)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```